# Installed older kernel in 20.04 but wireless, bluetooth and ethernet adapters are missing

Tags: drivers, 20.04, kernel

Right now I am running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS **5.8.0-36-generic**
But I wanted to install an older kernel i.e. **5.4.0-58-generic**

So I installed it by running the following command:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-5.4.0-58-generic linux-image-5.4.0-58-generic
```

And after this, I did all the necessary grub configurations so as to boot into the newly installed older kernel that is **5.4.0-58-generic**.

Below are the steps that I did for updating the grub:

1. Found the $menuentry_id_option for the submenu:

   `grep submenu /boot/grub/grub.cfg`
2. Found the $menuentry_id_option for the menu entry for the kernel I wanted to use:

   `grep gnulinux /boot/grub/grub.cfg`
3. Commented out my current default grub in /etc/default/grub and replaced it with the sub-menu's $menuentry_id_option from step one, and the selected kernel's $menuentry_id_option from step two, separated by >.

In my case it looked like:

```
#GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_DEFAULT="gnulinux-advanced-dc2515a0-8714-42c7-825a-ec047c6cfd6e>gnulinux-5.4.0-58-generic-advanced-dc2515a0-8714-42c7-825a-ec047c6cfd6e"
```

4. then updated the grub:

   `sudo update-grub`

Then rebooted the system.

But when I rebooted into the system, I saw that I am missing all the necessary adapters like wireless, bluetooh and ethernet as well.

So I ran the command: `lspci`, so as to check if they are identified or not and to my shock all were listed there.

Here is the output of `lspci`:

[Screenshot of output of lspci](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhdNh.png)

And one more thing I'd like to quote is earlier when I was running **5.4.0-58-generic**(before updating to **5.8.0-36-generic**), all my adapters were perfectly fine, Bluetooth, wifi and ethernet, everything was working.

Output of /lib/modules/5.4.0-58-generic:
[image: Output of /lib/modules/5.4.0-58-generic]
Ouput of /boot:
[image: Ouput of /boot]

Please help me, so that I can boot into the older kernel image with all the adapters working.

Comment: Please add the output of `ls /boot/vmlin*` and `ls /lib/modules/*/` to the question.

Comment: actually there is no directory in /boot starting with vmlinuz

Comment: You must install `linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-58-generic` to reach wireless, gpu and other modules.

Comment: Thank you so much @kenn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I have got my answer, all credit goes to this guy- https://askubuntu.com/users/81249/kenn

I just needed to do:

`sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-58-generic`

and a reboot.

That's all.

Thank you https://askubuntu.com/users/66509/n0rbert for contributing and helping.

Comment: Seem like the three 'files': linux-headers, linux-image and linux-modules-extra have to accompany each other for smooth working.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following:

1. Reboot the system into GRUB and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>, then select *Advanced options for Ubuntu* line, and then choose line with oldest Linux 5.4 and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to boot system using it.
2. Login to the system, open terminal to execute commands below to get General Availability (GA) 5.4 kernel back:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge linux-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 \
   linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 "linux-*5.8*"

   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install linux-generic linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
   ```
3. Reboot to use latest GA Linux 5.4 kernel version.

---

Note: to revert the changes and to use 5.8 HWE kernel execute `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04` .

Comment: As i said in my question, I cannot access internet at all in that kernel image, because, it shows **no adapter found** for Bluetooth, wifi and ethernet as well

Comment: Can you tell me, if there is any other way so that I can boot into this previous kernel image?

Comment: Reboot to GRUB and select oldest 5.4 kernel in advanced options.

Comment: Doing so is leading to the same issue

Comment: Then you have to boot from 20.04 livecd, then [chroot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery) to installed system to follow my answer above.

Comment: what if I go with this method?
https://itsfoss.com/upgrade-linux-kernel-ubuntu/

so as to roll back

Comment: I would recommend first to check [this screen](https://i0.wp.com/itsfoss.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/install-new-linux-kernel-8.png?resize=800%2C512&ssl=1) on your machine. You should have 5.4.0-42 here to boot.

Comment: yeah I am having it there.